MYSQL select similar records sorted by field from another table
I have these tables
movie_scores



id
movie_id
user_id
score




1
1
1
10


2
2
1
5



movies



id
name
collection




1
Interstellar
1


2
The Dark Knight
2


3
The Shining
1


4
Forrest Gump
2



Here we know that user_id 1 rated Interstellar and Dark knight with 10 and 5 appropriately. Knowing this i can recommend this user 2 movies - The Shining and Forrest Gump because they have similar collection with the first two movies. But since he rated Interstellar higher than The Dark Knight i can guess that he likes collection 1 more than collection 2.
So the order should be:

The Shining (same collection to Interstellar which user rated as 10)
Forrest Gump (same collection to the Dark Knight which user rated as
5)


I can think of a possible solution which is  described here , but it wont be optimal. Try with your data and let me know

@ErgestBasha ty, i will try

@nbk, nah it's just for test :)

SELECT name
FROM movies
JOIN (  -- subquery calculates average score for each collection, may use MAX instead
  SELECT movies.collection, AVG(movie_scores.score) avg_score
  FROM movie_scores
  JOIN movies ON movie_scores.movie_id = movies.id
             AND user_id = 1
  GROUP BY movies.collection
  ) avg_scores USING (collection)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  -- subquery checks that the film is not scored yet
  SELECT NULL
  FROM movie_scores
  WHERE movie_scores.movie_id = movies.id
    AND user_id = 1
  )
ORDER BY avg_scores.avg_score DESC

fiddle
PS. The query won't return the movies if there is no any scored movie from the collection. For to return them you'd use LEFT JOIN. For such movies the average score will be set to NULL - you may place them at the beginning or at the end of output with according additional sorting expression.

Thanks, that's what i wanted

Quick question, if i want to select just one movie from each collection i can add group by collection at the end of the query. And let's say my movies table has a release_date column which indicates a release date of the movie. How can i group by collection and get the latest movie from each collection?

@BobbyRedjeans if i want to select just one movie from each collection i can add group by collection at the end of the query Such query is incorrect  and will fail if ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled. How can i group by collection and get the latest movie from each collection? ROW_NUMBER() in CTE and select first in outer query.
